# How to reset password,Salt

Tags: php, mysql

I have some php scripts that enables my user to create an account using email. He then sets up a password which is hashed and a salt is generated and stored in my database. Now im working on reset password which works fine but the new password  (changed password even though its correct fails to verify an email because of the salt and hash used when registering)

**below is the Hash function i used to encrypt user_password**

```
public function hashFunction($password) {
        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
}
```

**this is my reset password (changes the password but changed password does not verify)**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["reset-password"])) {
        require_once('connect.php');
        $sql = "UPDATE `oasisdb`.`registration_data` SET `user_password` = '" . ($_POST["user_password"]). "' WHERE `registration_data`.`name` = '" . $_GET["name"] . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $success_message = "Password is reset successfully.";

    }
?>
<link href="demo-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
function validate_password_reset() {
    if((document.getElementById("user_password").value == "") && (document.getElementById("confirm_password").value == "")) {
        document.getElementById("validation-message").innerHTML = "Please enter new password!"
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("user_password").value  != document.getElementById("confirm_password").value) {
        document.getElementById("validation-message").innerHTML = "Both password should be same!"
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
<form name="frmReset" id="frmReset" method="post" onSubmit="return validate_password_reset();">
<h1>Reset Password</h1>
    <?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
    <div class="success_message"><?php echo $success_message; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="validation-message">
        <?php if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
    <?php echo $error_message; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="field-group">
        <div><label for="Password">Password</label></div>
        <div>
        <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" class="input-field"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="field-group">
        <div><label for="email">Confirm Password</label></div>
        <div><input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" class="input-field"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="field-group">
        <div><input type="submit" name="reset-password" id="reset-password" value="Reset Password" class="form-submit-button"></div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

**this is my mysql table**

```
CREATE TABLE `registration_data` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Lastly this is my login.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'update_user_info.php';
$db = new update_user_info();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

       // receiving the post params
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // get the user by email and password
        $user = $db->VerifyUserAuthentication($email, $password);

        if ($user != false) {
            // use is found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;        
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["phone"] = $user["phone"];
            $response["user"]["gender"] = $user["gender"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user is not found with the credentials
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Wrong E-mail or Password. Please try again!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // required post params is missing
        $response["error"] = TRUE; 
        $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters E-mail and Password is missing!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

**this is how hash is used on registration**

```
public function StoreUserInfo($name, $email, $password, $gender, $phone) {
        $hash = $this->hashFunction($password);
        $user_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registration_data(name, email, user_password, salt, gender, phone) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $email, $user_password, $salt, $gender, $phone);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Where do you use function for hash your password?
Second use please statament method for update/select or do any query for dont risk SQL Injection

Comment: have updated my question to accomodate how hashed is used on registration

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for my password reset page.
This includes password strength verification.
Maybe this will help u, you are free to use it.
 
You should merge it with your code yourself.
I'm using a `base64` encoded string to put in user info like what emailaddress and if its a valid code.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
require("mysql_config.php");
session_start();
$melding = "";
if (isset($_GET['usr']))
{
    $passwordresetcode = base64_decode($_GET['usr']);
}
else
{
    $passwordresetcode = '';
}
$strings = explode(', ', $passwordresetcode);

$email = $strings[0];
$code = $strings[1];

if(isset($_POST['resetpass'])){


     $query_login = " 
        UPDATE users SET 
        salt = :salt,
        password = :password
        WHERE email = '".$email."'
    "; 
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query_params = array( 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':password' => hash('sha256', $password . $salt)
        ); 

    try {  
        $stmt11 = $db->prepare($query_login); 
        $result = $stmt11->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query 2: " . $ex->getMessage()); }
    header("Location: login.php"); /* Redirect browser */ 
}
else{

$code = str_replace(' ', '', $code);
//$code = trim($code," ");
$stmt = $db->prepare("  
SELECT  *
FROM    users 
WHERE   email = '$email'
 ");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

if ($row)
{
    ?>  
    <link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />

    <div id="password_reset_form" class="col-X-6 col-xs-12" style="margin: 0 auto;">
   <h2>New password</h2>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" minlength='8' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
        <div id="progress">
          <div id="progress-bar"></div>
        </div> 
        <input type="password" id="repeat_pwd" name="repeatpassword" minlength='8' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Repeat Password">
        <div id="match" style="background: lightblue;">

        </div><br/>   
        <input type="submit" disabled id="resetpassword"  onclick="hide_form()" name="resetpass" class="button disabled" value="Verstuur">
        <br/><br/>
    </form>

    </div>

    <?php
    }
}
else{
echo 'No user found!';
}

?>
<script>
function hide_form(){
    $('#password_reset_form').css( "display", "none" );
}
function check(score){
  if($("#pwd").val() == $("#repeat_pwd").val()){
    $("#match").html("Passwords do not match!");
    $("#match").css("background-color", "#DFF2BF");
    if(score == 5){$("#resetpassword").prop('disabled', false); $("#resetpassword").removeClass("disabled");}else{$("#resetpassword").prop('disabled', true); $("#resetpassword").addClass("disabled"); $("#match").html("Password not strong enough!"); $("#match").css("background-color", "rgb(255, 182, 119)");}
  }
  else{
    $("#match").html("Passwords do not match!");
    $("#match").css("background-color", "#FFBABA");
   $("#resetpassword").prop('disabled', true);
 $("#resetpassword").addClass("disabled");  
  }
}
    var score = 0;
    function update_bar( element, password ) {
        var desc = [{'width':'0px'}, {'width':'20%'}, {'width':'40%'}, {'width':'60%'}, {'width':'80%'}, {'width':'100%'}];
        var descClass = ['', 'progress-bar-danger', 'progress-bar-danger', 'progress-bar-warning', 'progress-bar-warning', 'progress-bar-success'];
        score = 0;
        element.removeClass();
        if(password.length > 10) {
            score++;
        }
        if(password.length > 6) {
            score++;
        }
        if ( (password.match(/[a-z]/)) && (password.match(/[A-Z]/))) {
            score++;
        }
        if (password.match(/\d+/)) {
            score++;
        }
        if (password.match(/.[/,\\,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/)) {
            score++;
        }
        if (password.length > 8) {
            score++;
        }
        if(score > 5){
            score = 5;
        }

        element.addClass( descClass[score] );
        element.css( desc[score] );
       check(score);     
    }

  $("#pwd").keyup(function() {
     update_bar( $( "#progress-bar" ), $("#pwd").val() );

   });
$("#pwd").bind('paste', function(event) { 
     update_bar( $( "#progress-bar" ), $("#pwd").val() );         
}); 

$("#pwd").bind('change', function(event) { 
     update_bar( $( "#progress-bar" ), $("#pwd").val() );         
});     


$("#repeat_pwd").keyup(function() {
     check(score);     

   });
$("#repeat_pwd").bind('paste', function(event) { 
     check(score);            
}); 

$("#repeat_pwd").bind('change', function(event) { 
     check(score);              
});     




</script>


<style>
form {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
}
    h2{
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#progress {
  height: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#progress-bar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 500ms linear;
}
#match{
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-bar-danger {
  background: #d00;
}

.progress-bar-warning {
  background: #f50;
}

.progress-bar-success {
  background: #080;
}
    #password_reset_form{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
     #password_reset_form img{
        margin: 0 auto;
         display: table;

    }
      #password_reset_form form{
        margin: 0 auto;
         display: block;

    }

    body{
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

With php you can use these two function to get a securised hash of your password without saving a salt into your database :

password_hash() : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.password-hash.php

password_verify() : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.password-verify.php

It's very easy to use and shorter than a hash function. I think you can reset your password easily with this without salt problem in your code or database.